# Can Oracle's regular expression substring be used to retrieve "n" words before or after another string?

Tags: regex, oracle

I have written two functions which work, but I believe there may be a better (faster, more elegant) way, using regular expressions in Oracle.

The two functions will find a position within a string that is 'n' words before and a second function finds the position of 'n' words after. They look like this;

```
  FUNCTION FIND_POS_WORD_N_BEFORE(IN_WORD_POS IN BINARY_INTEGER, NUMBER_OF_WORDS_BACK IN BINARY_INTEGER, IN_STRING IN VARCHAR2) RETURN BINARY_INTEGER DETERMINISTIC
  IS
    CURRENT_POS BINARY_INTEGER := 0;
    LOOP_COUNT BINARY_INTEGER := 0;
    OUT_POS BINARY_INTEGER := 0;

  BEGIN
    WHILE CURRENT_POS + 1 < IN_WORD_POS OR (LOOP_COUNT > 0 AND CURRENT_POS = 0)
    LOOP
      LOOP_COUNT := LOOP_COUNT + 1;
      CURRENT_POS := INSTR(IN_STRING,' ',1,LOOP_COUNT);
      IF LOOP_COUNT > NUMBER_OF_WORDS_BACK
      THEN
        OUT_POS := INSTR(IN_STRING,' ',1,LOOP_COUNT-NUMBER_OF_WORDS_BACK);
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN OUT_POS + 1;
  END FIND_POS_WORD_N_BEFORE;

  FUNCTION FIND_POS_WORD_N_AFTER(IN_WORD_END_POS IN BINARY_INTEGER, NUMBER_OF_WORDS_AFTER IN BINARY_INTEGER, IN_STRING IN VARCHAR2) RETURN BINARY_INTEGER DETERMINISTIC
  IS
    CURRENT_POS BINARY_INTEGER := IN_WORD_END_POS;
    LOOP_COUNT BINARY_INTEGER := 0;
    OUT_POS BINARY_INTEGER := LENGTH(IN_STRING);

  BEGIN
    WHILE (LOOP_COUNT < NUMBER_OF_WORDS_AFTER + 1)
    LOOP
      LOOP_COUNT := LOOP_COUNT + 1;
      CURRENT_POS := INSTR(IN_STRING,' ',IN_WORD_END_POS,LOOP_COUNT) - 1;
    END LOOP;
    IF LOOP_COUNT >= NUMBER_OF_WORDS_AFTER  AND CURRENT_POS != -1
    THEN
      OUT_POS := CURRENT_POS;
    END IF;
    RETURN OUT_POS;
  END FIND_POS_WORD_N_AFTER;
```

You pass in the starting (or ending for after) position of the target string, how many words back or forward, and the string. I would use it like this; (I would probably split this into multiple lines for readability)

```
SELECT SUBSTR(:test_string,FIND_POS_WORD_N_BEFORE(instr(:test_string,'moderately'), 3,:test_string),instr(:test_string,'moderately')-FIND_POS_WORD_N_BEFORE(instr(:test_string,'moderately'), 3,:test_string))
FROM dual;
```

where :test_string is;

```
this is a test of a moderately long group of words
```

and it would return;

```
test of a
```

What I am hoping is that someone that knows Oracle regexp_substr well enough to write this as a single line of code.

Answer (score 1):

OK I think I understand what you want: given a string, you specify a position or a word and you want a predefined number of words after or before that word.

Let's assume the input string: `this is a test of a moderately long group of words`.
I am assuming the words contain only alphanumeric characters and underscores `_`.
I am assuming the words are separated by spaces.

**Warning:** I think your functions will be more efficient than using regular expressions.

## Case 1: Before the word

If you want to get the 3 words right before `moderately` in the sentence then you can use:

```
(?:\w+|\s){6}(?=moderately)
       ^^  ^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^
       | double number| of words you need
       |              |
       |          the word you want to look before
      the separator, if there is more than one possible type of separator then
      put them in character class like this: [\s;REST_OF_SEPARATORS]
```

You can insert the number of words and the word to search before inside the regular expression string by using Oracle's concatenation operator or whatever appropriate.

[Regex 101 Demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/lA1zQ3)

## Case 2: After the word

If you want to get the 2 words right after `long` in the sentence then you can use:

```
(?<=long)(?:\w+|\s){4}
```

The same thing here, replace `{4}` for your input number and replace `long` with your chosen word.

[Regex 101 Demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/mP3bC8)

Comment: First thanks for the help, especially highlighting the regular expression parts. I will try it out shortly. 

But I have a question, Why do you think my routine might be faster than the regexp_substr? I know regular expressions can be slow, but slower than my mess of code?

Comment: @PaulStearns I haven't taken a deep look at your code, but I think it will be faster because Oracle regular expression engine is uses the POSIX standard so it will always try to find the longest match, and with the expressions I gave you, especially this part `(?:\w+|\s){4}` where you apply the repetition to a `+` operator. Anyway I haven't done any benchmarking and this is a wild guess so I could be totally wrong, I just wanted to throw a warning so you can take notice.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you three words before and after the desired word.

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR (source_string, '([^ ]+ +){3}moderately( +[^ ]+){3}')
```